# Verifying Equivalence with Sec(x) and Identities

Tags: integration

I'm trying to prove a couple of different problems and I'm having difficulty proving them on my own and could use a little help and advice.

The first thing I needed to prove that this identity is true:
$$\ sec(x) = \frac{cos(x)} {|1 -sin^2x|}$$ 
Which I've done and have proven. Now I have to use that information to prove this:

$$\int sec(x) dx = \frac{|1+sinx|}{|1-sinx|}+C$$ 
I'm very unsure of how to go about this. I've tried taking the derivative of the problem and have gotten no where. I think I may need to do integration by partial fractions. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I don't get why you are putting the absolute sign there, which is redundant since $1 \pm sinx$ is always positive anyway.

so the first identity would just be:
$$\ sec(x) = \frac{cos(x)} {1 -sin^2x}$$

Now I think you might have a typo in the second identity (missing a factor of two). the correct formula should be :
$$\int sec(x) dx = \frac{1+sinx}{2(1-sinx)}+C$$

Now if we do take derivative on the right side of second identity, using quotient rule, we get 
$$\bigg(\frac{1+sinx}{2(1-sinx)}\bigg)' = \frac{(1-sinx)cosx - (1+sinx)(-cosx)}{2(1-sinx)^2} = \frac{cosx}{(1-sinx)^2}=sec(x)$$ 
thus proving 
$$\int sec(x) dx = \frac{1+sinx}{2(1-sinx)}+C$$